# Validation of IP address with three methods but breaks when I try to validate 0 - 255 octet

Tags: java, loops, methods, boolean, ip-address

I know there are easier ways to do this project. BUT that is not the path our professor wanted us to take. Ergo, I need some assistance.

What I am attempting to do is validate an IP address with four sections, three periods and values between 0 and 255 for each segment. And there is a catch, I have to have **THREE methods** to do so.

**First**: Verify three dots and segmentation

**Second**: Identify that the octet have a valid number between 0 and 255

**Third**: Identify that it is an integer (*Please note this method is not yet implemented because of the current bug. I pretty much understand what to do with this because it was basically our last project.*)

Currently as the code is it breaks when I try to validate the number range 0 - 255. I did get it to work validating the periods and segments with the correct amount of numbers but not the total value.

Seems to break where the "`for (String f : octet)`" starts. It's like it will not carry the octet value down from the other method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And thank you in advanced!

```
   /*
 * File name: IsAValidIPAddress.java
 * Project name: Is a Valid IP Address
 * 
 * Creator's name: Joshua Trimm
 * Email: jbthype@gmail.com
 * Course and section: CISP 1010
 * Creation Date: 10-11-17
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * <b>Validation of IP Address using three methods</b>
 * <hr>
 * Date created: 10-9-2017
 * <hr>
 * @author Joshua Trimm
 * 
 */
public class IsAValidIPAddress 
{
    /*
     * Method description: This is the main method
     * @param args
     * @return void
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Scanner
        Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        //prompt user
        System.out.print("Enter a valid IP address e.g. 192.168.1.100: ");
        String validate = consoleInput.nextLine();

        //define the boolean that pass from isAValidIPAddress
        boolean isTrue = isAValidIPAddress(validate);

        //while loop
        while(isTrue == true)
        {
            System.out.println(validate + " is a valid IP address,");
            System.out.print("Enter another valid IP address: ");
            validate = consoleInput.nextLine();
        }

        //Tell the user if it is invalid
        System.out.print(validate + " is not a valid number, bye!");
        //close the console input
        consoleInput.close();
    }

/*
 * Method description: validates if the string has three periods and there are four sections
 * @param string
 * @return boolean
 */

    //is a valid IP Address boolean and that it has three periods and that it is numbers only
    private static boolean isAValidIPAddress(String ipAddress)
    {

        //check to see if the octet is true
        boolean isTrue = isAValidOctet(ipAddress);

        //Create a while loop to check if results are true

        //define local variables
        boolean isTrueipAddress = true;

        int i1 = 0;

        int length = ipAddress.length();
        if(ipAddress.isEmpty() )
        {
            isTrueipAddress = false;

        }



            if(!(ipAddress.contains(".")))
            {
                //no period was found
                isTrueipAddress = false;

            }
            else
            {
                String [] segments = ipAddress.split("\\.");
                if(!(segments.length == 4))
                {
                    isTrueipAddress = false;

                }


        }
        //String moveTest == segments();
        return isTrueipAddress;


    }

/*
 * Method description: Validate that each section has only 4 three numbers and values between 0 - 255
 * @param string
 * @return boolean
 */     

        // is a valid octet boolean. Make sure the numbers verify 0 - 255 for each octet
    private static boolean isAValidOctet(String octet)
    {

        boolean isTrueOctet = true;
        int i = 0;
        int [] validation = new int[4];


        // here the string doesn't seem two want to pass from the previous method. "octet"
        for (String f : octet)
        {
            try
            {
                validation[i] = Integer.parseInt(f);
                if((validation[i] < 0) || (validation[i] > 255))
                {
                    isTrueOctet = false;
                }
                i++;
            }
            catch (Exception g)
            {
                isTrueOctet = false;
            }
        }

        return isTrueOctet;
    }

}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: You are calling it as `boolean isTrue = isAValidOctet(ipAddress);`  - an ipaddress is not an octet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code to

```
String [] segments = ipAddress.split("\\.");
if(!(segments.length == 4))
{
    return false;
}
return isAValidOctet(segments);
```

Also in `isAValidOctet` change to

```
if((validation[i] < 0) || (validation[i] > 255))
{
    // isTrueOctet = false;
    // may as well return now
    return false;
}
```

**Also** not really necessary to store into `validation` - just keep in a local variable

**Edit**

You are passing in a String array, so your method should be

```
private static boolean isAValidOctet(String[] octet)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Scary Wombat! Unfortunately it is still throwing an "Unresolved compilation problem" @ line 121... `for (String f : octet)`

Comment: Cool, that helped!  However, I can still enter in values greater than 255 per segment. e.i. 777.777.777.777.  Thank you again @Scary Wombay! Love your name BTW! :-)

Comment: Can't up vote yet. Still too new. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Scary Wombat for your help! Please view below for the corrected coding.

```
package numbers;

/*
 * File name: IsAValidIPAddress.java
 * Project name: Is a Valid IP Address
 * 
 * Creator's name: Joshua Trimm
 * Email: jbthype@gmail.com
 * Course and section: CISP 1010
 * Creation Date: 10-11-17
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * <b>Validation of IP Address using three methods</b>
 * <hr>
 * Date created: 10-9-2017
 * <hr>
 * @author Joshua Trimm
 * 
 */
public class IsAValidIPAddress 
{
    /*
     * Method description: This is the main method
     * @param args
     * @return void
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Scanner
        Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        //prompt user
        System.out.print("Enter a valid IP address e.g. 192.168.1.100: ");
        String validate = consoleInput.nextLine();

        //define the boolean that pass from isAValidIPAddress
        boolean isTrue = isAValidIPAddress(validate);

        //while loop
        //while(isTrue == true)
        while(isTrue) // SC - why have this loop at all? it does no processing
        {
            System.out.println(validate + " is a valid IP address,");
            System.out.print("Enter another valid IP address: ");
            validate = consoleInput.nextLine();
            break;
        }

        //Tell the user if it is invalid
        System.out.print(validate + " is not a valid number, bye!");
        //close the console input
        consoleInput.close();
    }

/*
 * Method description: validates if the string has three periods and there are four sections
 * @param string
 * @return boolean
 */

    //is a valid IP Address boolean and that it has three periods and that it is numbers only
    private static boolean isAValidIPAddress(String ipAddress)
    {

        //check to see if the octet is true
        //boolean isTrue = isAValidOctet(ipAddress);

        //Create a while loop to check if results are true

        //define local variables
        boolean isAvalidIPAddress = true;
        String [] segments = ipAddress.split("\\.");
        int i1 = 0;

        // int length = ipAddress.length();  // SC this variable is not used
        if(segments.length != 4 || !(ipAddress.contains(".")) || ipAddress.isEmpty())
        {
            // isAvalidIPAddress = false;
            // SC normally return as soon as possible 
            return false;  // then do not need else statement

        }
        //else
        //{
        return isAValidOctet(segments);
        //}
        //return isAvalidIPAddress;
}
        //String moveTest == segments();





/*
 * Method description: Validate that each section has only 4 three numbers and values between 0 - 255
 * @param string
 * @return boolean
 */     

        // is a valid octet boolean. Make sure the numbers verify 0 - 255 for each octet
    private static boolean isAValidOctet(String[] octet)
    {

        // boolean isTrueOctet = true;
        // int i = 0;
        // SC why use an array ?
        // int [] validation = new int[4];


        // here the string doesn't seem two want to pass from the previous method. "octet"
        for (String f : octet)
        {
            try
            {
                //validation[i] = Integer.parseInt(f);
                int part = Integer.parseInt(f);
                if((part < 0) || (part > 255))
                {
                    //isTrueOctet = false;
                    // SC again retun ASAP
                    return false;
                }
                // i++;
            }
            catch (Exception g)
            {
                //isTrueOctet = false;
                // maybe log exception
                return false;
            }
        }

        //return isTrueOctet;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: joshua I have edited your code and have commented why. Although [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to do so